# invalid method in /lib/Varien/Object.php after update, causing maintenance mode

Tags: module, magento-1, methods, varien

I just updated some modules and now my webshop keeps showing the maintenance page, whilst there is not maintenance.flag file in the root folder.

I checked the /var/log and in the exception.log it keeps showing this error:

```
2015-09-30T10:33:15+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Itoffshore_Products_Block_Price::callParentToHtml(Array
(
)
)' in /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
Stack trace:
#0 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php(398): Varien_Object->__call('callParentToHtm...', Array)
#1 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php(398): Itoffshore_Products_Block_Price->callParentToHtml()
#2 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/design/frontend/default/aman-mobile/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(62): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract->getTierPriceHtml()
#3 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/ama...')
#4 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#5 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#9 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#11 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/design/frontend/default/aman-mobile/template/page/1column.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#12 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/users/ama...')
#13 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#14 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#18 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(147): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#19 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(332, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#20 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#21 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#22 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/users/amanvftp/amanvida.eu/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```

When I check the Object.php file I indeed notice that the callParentToHTML method does not exist. And according to the documentation, it shouldn't exist.

http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?lib/Varien/Object.php.source.html

1. How do I resolve this issue?
2. Is this the reason why my site is showing the maintenance page or should I dig deeper? And how would I troubleshoot the issue that is causing this. (Funny thing is the maintenance page is only showing for the product pages and cart, not for homepage and category pages.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seams you have an extension called `Itoffshore_Products` containing this block `Itoffshore_Products_Block_Price` and this block does not contain the method `callParentToHtml`.
The first thing you can try is to add this in the block mentioned above

```
protected function callParentToHtml()
{
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

Clear the cache and see what happens.
If that doesn't work, contact the extension developer for support.

Comment: It partially solves the problem. Instead of the the maintenance page I now see an error at the place where the HTML block is supposed to come. Contacting the developer.